# Testing differences in 5 star rating (Which hotel to choose)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, median

Say, I want to choose a Hotel with the following ratings (1-5) on TripAdvisor.
This seemed interesting if the mean for the Hotel with smaller number of votes is bigger than the mean of the hotel with larger number of votes.

**Example 1:**

Mean Hotel 1 (4.5), with n=2

Mean Hotel 2 (3.77), with n=147

Frequency table:

```
|         | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  |
|---------|----|----|----|----|----|
| Hotel 1 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  |
| Hotel 2 | 18 | 14 | 27 | 41 | 47 |
```

**Example 2:**

Mean Hotel 1 (4.85), with n=19

Mean Hotel 2 (4.03), with n=38

```
|         | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | 5  |
|---------|---|---|---|----|----|
| Hotel 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 3  | 14 |
| Hotel 2 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 14 | 18 |
```

**Analysis**

I would like to know what test I should do for comparison.
Treating the rating as ordinal value for two independent groups I was thinking of the following tests: Mann-Withney-U, Mean-Test, Chi2-Test

I would conclude the following;

Example1:

- Mann-Whitney-U (Yates-corrected): p = 0.20

  - Not ideal, because I cannot assume identical distributions
- Chi2: p = 0.89

  - Not suited, because some cells in expected table have <5 counts
- Median-Test (ignoring values at grand median): p = 0.78

  - Should be applicable, suggests not to reject H0 (that both medians are equal) at 5% level.

Example 2:

- Same as above for Chi2 and Mann-Whitney-U
- Median-Test: In scipy.stats I have to set how ties are dealt with. Ignoring ties, the test does not work as the grand median is 5. (Unless I set the option to count values at the grand median to be counted as "above median".)

**Q1**: Would you say this "in general" is the right approach. (I presume sample sizes are too small for powerful testing)?

**Q2**: How would I deal with example 2?

**Bonus Q3**: Could I do any statistical comparison in the case that I only have given the mean and the sample size for each Hotel?

Comment: Well, you are aware that you are just counting who paid more to these ( https://www.buybulkreviews.com/buy-tripadvisor-reviews-starting-only-3-15/ ) guys, right?

Comment: Sure, I have been traveling long enough to know its basically a scam. Just intended as an example. Thank you for the link anyway, honestly I wasnt aware manipulation is so bluntly offered.

Comment: Indeed! It appears as a Google featured search if you type "Buy positive opinions for TripAdvisor"

Comment: You may want to try a "5 vs not-5" $\chi^2$-independence test. This could do the job in case 2. I don't think it is possible to get any meaningful conclusions for example 1